# I want to keep track of each action (button) user perform on pdf viewer

Tags: javascript, angular

On different browsers, the view is different. I want to keep track of each action like which button press by the user on the PDF viewer.
I'm creating the `iframe` and then set its attributes.
Is it possible to do that?
[image]

Comment: Does it work?`document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.body.addEventListener('click',() => console.log('click'));`. Note, this may not work if it's cross-domain. Also, I understand this is not the full solution, but could be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to a wide question, has to be, *"not possible"* without installing a "KeyLogger" or using an internal PDF JavaScript to "exploit" the users privacy. perhaps look at breakout game https://github.com/osnr/horrifying-pdf-experiments
[image]

From a programming point of view there are 3 types of PDF reader.

Full exploitable PDF binary readers you would need to attack from inside, If the user allows internal JavaScripts to run ! (One basic reason you dont see SWFlash anymore). These are the current browsing majority.

Full PDF binary readers that have JavaScript not available (I support one of those).
You would have absolutely no way of knowing, what if anything is active, inside the editing frame. The PDF AND keyboard commands are fully outside the browser, under client hardware control. There are very few of these secured PDF browsers as they were dropped from mainstream browsers. However from the section above you can see some majority users may have scripting disabled.

JavaScript iFrame PDF converters where the PDF is held inside a sandbox, much like the others, but the HTML components are images and text. Those you might be able to follow some very limited actions, but I think hardware feedback is very limited.